# System UI crash in Device, When i install the application created by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

The Issue that i'm facing is that when i install the application that i have made in android studio the system UI crashes no matter which mobile i install it to.The other thing is that if i press the recent tabs button it'll always crash.even then when i try uninstalling that application my Application Crashes and i'm not able to uninstall the application. can anyone help me with what should i do to stop facing these issues bcos i cant test my application not as the system UI keeps crashing.

UPDATE : issues is solved as the problem was that the icon that i was using for the logo was very big in size due to which the application would crash.

Comment: Any error show in `Logcat`. If yes then please paste hear

Comment: no i have tried a lot to get the Logcat error but i could not see any during the crash

Comment: please paste SS of your  `Logcat`

Comment: i got the issue the image that i was using for the launcher icon was very large in size due to which the application would crash